# How to validate remote ssl certificate?

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I want to validate a remote SSL Certificate.

I have an instance of **X509Certificate2** and access it with:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.paypal.com/de/webapps/mpp/home");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;
X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);
byte[] rawdata = cert2.RawData;
MessageBox.Show(cert2.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.EmailName,true));
```

But how do i know now, that it really is MY certificate?

So how do i validate it now?
if i make:

Dummycode:

if(Certificate.URL = "MYSAFEURL.COM") {//OK}

Someone could "modify" strings in my .exe to change MYSAFEURL to whatever.com

So is there any way to be 100% sure that the certificate is real?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate X509 certificate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613615/how-to-validate-x509-certificate)

Comment: No i saw this question but found no solution to verify a certificate properly.

Comment: It would then help if you could provide a little more information on what you are trying to do. What kind of client is this, what kind of server does it talk to and what exactly do you want to validate?

Comment: My C# Programm does a communication with my debian root server. (Login, Api's,etc) I want to verify, that my server responds and not a crackers one. If you route your windows hosts file to another ip, you could bypass login for example.

Comment: So your client contains certain functions that you do not want anyone to access until they have logged in to your server? That is not something that can be secured using certificates; if an attacker can alter the client, they can as well remove the whole server authentication part and simply use the functions you meant to protect.

Comment: But is there no way to secure the application?

Comment: It might be possible to _"secure the application"_, but then: _"It would then help if you could provide a little more information on what you are trying to do. What kind of client is this, what kind of server does it talk to and what exactly do you want to validate?"_. What does the client do, what does the server do, how do you think it is best secured?

Comment: my main problem is to validate answers from my server to the client.the client is a small c# program with login and api calls. i could think of adding a cryptic header to my php api, and my c# programm has an algorithm implented do "decode" this header. if decoding is true, it is verified? or any other solutions?

Comment: Again, you must assume someone can alter your client. If they can do so, they can remove any clientside validation. Why is it so important for you to secure the _client_?

Comment: mhhh... good question. i thought securing the client would be a good idea. so you think i should focus on securing my application through my server?

Comment: That still depends on what exactly you are doing. Please try to imagine what exactly somebody could do, and how it would harm you, if they are talking to their own server using your client. Describe any possible problems that can arise and update your question with that. If for example your client contains some unique code, say a calculation of some sort, you should try to move that to the server code and call that only using parameters, and so on. Then a compromised client cannot do any harm, because it cannot reach your server and not do the calculation.

Comment: I want to prevent piracy by protecting it. they cannot "harm" my server with junk data or anything else. it is just a piracy protection. so i want to do a login and maybe some "random pings" to my server, to check if my app is cracked or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can Sign the URL

```
 if((Hash(Certificate.URL) = Decrypt("UrlSignature")) {//OK}

With "UrlSignature" = Encrypt(Hash("MYSAFEURL.COM"))
```

Hash can be SHA256

Encrypt and decrypt is an asymetric encryption like RSA

You encrypt with the private key

You decrypt with the public Key

Comment: Can you explain why this solves his problem? strings can still be modified, please expand a little.