# C# verify file certificate

Tags: c#, x509certificate, digital-signature, verification

I want to verify file certificate. The signature was generating using sha1 and RSA.
When right clicking the file, selecting properties, Digital Signatures, Details I see the following:

[image]

I have C++ code that verifies such a signature, using `WinVerifyTrust`.

However I googled - I just couldn't find C# way of doing it.
I tried to export the certificate to file, and then took from the file properties the Message Digest:
[image]
Create `X509 Certificate`, and verify hash - nothing worked.

Any help will be appreciated.

**CLARIFICATION**

In short: Given a file, how can I verify it is signed by a trusted certificate?

Comment: X509Certificate2.Verify()
Se this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613615/how-to-validate-x509-certificate

Comment: @Oscar - but how do I get the cert the file was signed with? I want all the process be done programatically....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get timestamp from Authenticode Signed files in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281057/get-timestamp-from-authenticode-signed-files-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for :  [**X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.createfromsignedfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 try
  {
  X509Certificate theSigner = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile("c:\\r\\1.dll");
  Console.Write("certificate info :"+ theSigner.GetCertHashString());
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
         Console.WriteLine("No digital signature ");


  }
```

Comment: The problem is that this approach gives one certitficate and not all the certificates included in the Authenticode signature.

Comment: Is there not a way to iterate them?