# Validate certificate in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssl, windows-8

I can't use the System.Security library due to restrictions on the windows 8 applications. I need to use Windows.Security.Cryptography and I need to validate that a certificate (.cer file) and a key (.key file) are a valid pair.

I'm already reading the file and creating a new instance of a certificate:

```
Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.Certificate objCert = new Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.Certificate(stream);
```

stream being the .cer file as an IBuffer.

I can extract some of the properties of the .cer file like expiration or issuer,  but I can't get the key that it was signed with, and compare it to the key contained in the .key file.

Comment: What is the key for? Is it the signing key of the issuer, or is it the private key for the subject's public key?

Comment: *"... but I can't get the key that it was signed with..."* - right. You should not be able to access the issuer's private key because its a private key :) The issuer keeps the private/signing key, and distributes the public key. Similar to what PID said, about the most you can do is probably some test against the Authority Key Identifier (AKI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't compare those keys. You normally compare their hash codes. This is so, because you don't give away the private key.

The certificate has a hash code of the private key. From the key file you can compute that same hash code. Once you have both hash codes you can compare them.

[GetCertHashString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getcerthashstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Don't put the private key in the cer file, keep there only the public key and that hash of the private key.

Also look here: [How to validate X509 certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613615/how-to-validate-x509-certificate)

Comment: *"How to validate X509 certificate..."* - `System.Security` is not available.

Comment: I apologize, what do you mean with "is not available"? Where? In your assembly? Please be more specific, I don't understand you :)

Comment: The question states *"I can't use the System.Security ibrary..."*. You'll have to ask user2868383 for the particular reason. I can provide an answer using OpenSSL (and not `System.Security`), but I need to know what keys he/she has first.

Comment: Ah, ok :) I missed that, thanks for pointing it out. Well... then... no dice!

Comment: Windows 8 Apps don't support the class System.Security.Cryptography.
Have a look at the MSDN page (System.Security.Cryptography namespace):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eat8fht.aspx[^]
If a class is supported in Windows 8 Apps, then there's a little green suitcase shown in the most left column.

I can use Windows.Security.Cryptography

Comment: I don't create certificates, they are created by a goverment institution, they provide the .cer and the .key file I need to verify that the files are a valid pair.