# How to validate SSL certificate with BouncyCastle csharp

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate, bouncycastle

I have to validate several SSL certificates in a none-browser application for `HttpRequests` and `websocket` connections. I am using a plugin which handles those http and websocket connection which in turn uses the [bouncycastle csharp](https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) for the validation of the certificates. However the "validation" part has to be done by me by implementing the `ICertificateVerifyer` which should contain the validation check in the `isValid` method;

```
public interface ICertificateVerifyer
{
    bool IsValid(Uri targetUri, X509CertificateStructure[] certs);
}
```

In theory I know what I have to do but my problem is the implementation and how to utilize the bouncycastle library for that. I do not have an in depth knowledge of cryptography but after some reading I think I know the steps I want to to do in order to verify a certificate however it lacks in knowing "how" to implement it.

**1. Chain-of-trust verification**

My first naive approach was to have a string comparison of `certs[0].Issuer.ToString()` and `certs[1].Subject.ToString()` which worked but is properly not a good idea. Therefore I found this implementation in [Java](https://gist.github.com/the-dan/1188374) which (as far as I understood it) checks if the public certificate of the parent was used to sign the child's certificate. This sounds more reasonable but I was not able to port it to bouncycastle csharp because I was not able to extract the `modulus` and `exp` integer from the public key of the parent.

I also did not understand why the implementation only handles the case of 2 certificates in the certs array. My understanding was that it also could be the case that there could be a longer chain of certificates and that only the bottom one is the server certificate and the most top one should be a root CA.

The other thing what I am missing is the "check" that the root CA must be one of the clients trusted CAs. I have no idea how to do that nor how load CAs.

**2. Hostname verification**

This looks easy at first glance easy since I get `certs[0].Subject{CN="myDomainIwanttoverify}` but according to [RFC2818] [3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818) you should use the "SubjectAltNames" and not the "Common Name" which I guess is the Property `CN`. Again I have no idea how to do that.

**3. Certificate revocation**

This is one part I have no clue about how to do it nor did I find any implementation which I understood and was able to use. As far as I understood it, I have to provide in addition to the CA (for the Chain-of-Trust verification) a Certificate revocation List (CLR). If so, isn't it essential to this mechanism to update this list as frequent as possible?

I know this is a complex topic but as far as I understood it, most none-browser application are not validating the certificate or "doing it wrong" and I would like to, at least, try my best.

Comment: X509 chaining validation including revocation list and hostname comparison is built into the framework. Is there a particular reason why you have to use BouncyCastle? If alternatives are possible, refer to this first and see if it already meets your requirements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613615/how-to-validate-x509-certificate

Comment: Unfortunately I am forced to use BouncyCastle.

Comment: why? I'd better to use `X509Chain` class over BC any time. This class fully implements RFC5280 certificate validation rules.

Comment: you are right, but this is a different usecase. I guess I will create a new question for that.

Comment: I create a new question regarding the same issue but now with `X509Chain` validation.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865326/how-to-proper-validate-ssl-certificate-with-x509certificate2-on-mono-and-multipl