# How to proper validate SSL certificate with X509Certificate2 on Mono and multiple platforms

Tags: c#, mono, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

I have to validate several SSL certificates in a none-browser application for `HttpRequests` and `websocket` connections which should run on IOS, Android and Linux.
When a connection via `HTTPS` happens I receive an array of `X509Certificate2` objects where the bottom one is the server certificate and the most top one the root CA (hopefully). As an example, when I connect to `https://google.com` I receive 3 `X509Certificate2` with the following `SubjectName.Name`:

- 0 : `"CN=google.com, O=Google Inc, L=Mountain View, S=California, C=US"`
- 1 : `"CN=Google Internet Authority G2, O=Google Inc, C=US"`
- 2 : `"CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US"`

I now need to verify the certificate validation with the given information and the following verifications:

- Chain-of-trust verification
- Hostname verification
- Certificate revocation verification

**What I tried and not understood and failed:**

When I call the `X509Certificate2.Verify()` method on each certificate independently it returns `false` everytime. I also do not understand why it can return anything else then `false` because the verification happens independently. Instead the complete chain, meaning all certificates, should be checked as far as I understood the theory.

I then used the `X509Chain` class:

```
foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in allthreecerts)
    {
        X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
        X509ChainPolicy chainPolicy = new X509ChainPolicy()
        {
            RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Offline,
            RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain
        };
        chain.ChainPolicy = chainPolicy;
        if (!chain.Build(cert))
        {
            foreach (X509ChainElement chainElement in chain.ChainElements)
            {
                foreach (X509ChainStatus chainStatus in chainElement.ChainElementStatus)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(chainStatus.StatusInformation);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This prints out `RevocationStatusUnknown` and `OfflineRevocation` for each certificate.

Again, I do not understand why this should work since a chain is build which each certificate independently. Should not be the parent certificate be the Issue of the child certificate all down to the root CA?

**What I think I need somehow but do not know how.**

In order to verify the certificate revocation all clients need to provide a certificate revocation list. Where do I get such a list and where to I load it and tell the chain to use this local list?

The same problem is the Chain-of-trust verification since the last certification should be a root certification and must be one of the clients trusted root CA's. So I have to load, for example, all root CA which are shipped with Firefox and check if the root CA is one of them? What is the best way to do that?

[Update]
I made a copy paste mistake in the `google.com` example where I pasted two identical certificate subject names.

Comment: `RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Offline` -- switch it to `Online`. Client must have local CRL/OCSP cache to successfully validate revocation in offline mode.

Comment: Well that is the point. I am implementing the "client". So how to I provide such CRL. That was the question I am asking.

Comment: CRLs are retrieved from online resources. CRL locations are specified in the `CRL Distribution Points` certificate extension. Or in the `On-line Certificate Status Protocol` section in `Authority Information Access` extension.

Comment: thanks, are there any helper in .NET where I can load such a .crl file and search through it to check if a specific certificate is already revoked?

Comment: You can use bouncy castle to parse CRL. Maybe Mono also has something but I am not very familiar with Mono.

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? `X509Chain.Build()` does all you need. Including revocation checking.

Answer (score 2):

> When a connection via HTTPS happens I receive an array of X509Certificate2 objects where the bottom one is the server certificate and the most top one the root CA (hopefully).

If you really did get root ca certificate from SSL server then the SSL server is not configured correctly. It should return its server certificate and the whole chain Except the root CA certificate.

> When I call the X509Certificate2.Verify() method on each certificate independently it returns false everytime.

As stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify(v=vs.110).aspx) of X509Certificate2.Verify method `This method builds a simple chain for the certificate and applies the base policy to that chain.` Now what is `the base policy` I do not know. But on of the default values of `ChainPolicy` is `RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online`. As for Mono the source of this method can be found [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/ef407901f8fdd9ed8c377dbec8123b5afb932ebb/mcs/class/System/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/X509Certificate2.cs#L644). The source of Mono implementation of X509Chain can be found [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/ef407901f8fdd9ed8c377dbec8123b5afb932ebb/mcs/class/System/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/X509Chain.cs#L111).

> This prints out RevocationStatusUnknown and OfflineRevocation for each certificate.

What else should it print when you specified RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Offline and there are no CRLs or OCSP responses in cache (probably)?

> In order to verify the certificate revocation all clients need to provide a certificate revocation list. Where do I get such a list and where to I load it and tell the chain to use this local list?

Each certificate (well except root ca certificate) in the chain contains a link (or links) to CRL. .NET and most likely Mono too [has](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/ef407901f8fdd9ed8c377dbec8123b5afb932ebb/mcs/class/System/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/X509Chain.cs#L826) an implementation that will find link to CRL in the certificate, will download it and will check if the certificate is not revoked.

> The same problem is the Chain-of-trust verification since the last certification should be a root certification and must be one of the clients trusted root CA's. So I have to load, for example, all root CA which are shipped with Firefox and check if the root CA is one of them? What is the best way to do that?

No, `RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain` will do that for you using some store that mono uses. I don't know if it is the Firefox store but on Linux it has its own store and you can import root ca certificates from Firefox store. Check ChainElements and see for yourself what certificates did it find.

I would suggest that you build the chain with SSL server certificate only (as this will check all certs in the chain upwards) with `RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online` and `RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain`. I would also try to set [ExtraStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chainpolicy.extrastore(v=vs.110).aspx) property of X509Chain to a list of certificate you got from SSL server. After the Build method I would chceck ChainStatus property of X509Chain object which is an array of statuses. I would pick all statuses that have not set [X509ChainStatus.Status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chainstatus.status(v=vs.110).aspx) to NoError. If there will be any such status I would throw and log each X509ChainStatus.Status and  [X509ChainStatus.StatusInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chainstatus.statusinformation(v=vs.110).aspx).

HTH

Comment: This is the part I do not understand. How can `X509Certificate2.Verify` build a complete chain if this is only one certificate of the chain? I set the `RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online` which produces the exact same results. 
The `ExtraStore` property has a private setter so I cannot set it. But if the CRL download/checking and also if a CA store is used then should't it already work (when using `RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online`) ?

Comment: The ChainStatus property of the X509Chain always contains 3 elements. "PartialChain","RevocationStatusUnknown" and "OfflineRevocation" even with `RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online`

Comment: @zlZimon `X509Certificate2.Verify` uses some Mono certificate store to look for certificates to build chain. SSL server does (should not) send root ca certificate so you as client have to build chain against your certificate store where you have trusted root ca certificates. Try tlstest from [this site](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/security/). Also on this page you will find `Note that a default installation of Mono doesn’t trust anyone!` so you need to fill trusted root certificates manually using `certmgr.exe` or `mozroots.exe`.

Comment: well unfortunatly I have to use a very old Mono version (2.6) so only `mozroots.exe` will work. Unfortunately I am on a mac....

Comment: ok I now installed a VM with windows and run the `mozroots.exe` --sync --import. I get the following error: `Downloading from 'http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt?raw=1'...
No certificates were found.` When I paste the link in the browser I get a Service Outage from mozilla... so where do I get another link which I can use?

Comment: I found an alternative link which uses the same data: `http://anduin.linuxfromscratch.org/BLFS/other/certdata.txt` however I get an error again:`Downloading from 'http://anduin.linuxfromscratch.org/BLFS/other/certdata.txt'...
Importing certificates into user store...
Error: System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.get_Hash()
   bei Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection.IndexOf(X509Certificate value)
   bei Mono.Tools.MozRoots.Process()
   bei Mono.Tools.MozRoots.Main(String[] args)`

Comment: @zlZimon What to say, Mono 2.6 is from 2009/2010. I would be terrified to use it :)

Comment: @pepo "If you really did get root ca certificate from SSL server then the SSL server is not configured correctly" it is not correct. There is no such requirement.

Comment: @CryptoGuy You are right. I based that on the results of [SSL test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) (if I remember correctly). According to [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93157/in-ssl-server-handshake-does-server-also-send-ca-certificate) and the referenced RFC within SSL server is not required to send Root CA certificate but may do so. To me it does not make sense to send Root CA certificate. I would not trust this Root CA and go with my own Trusted CA list.

Comment: @peop What to say, I am terrified but I have no choice.

Comment: well I did not manage to get mozroots.exe working... is there any other way to get the root certificates into a mono 2.6.5 version?

Comment: @zlZimon what about cert-sync command? I know it has been added in version 3.12.0 but maybe you could copy it from newer mono to your 2.6 mono.

Comment: @pepo well I think I managed to import those certificate somehow... how can I check if there are certificates in the store in code? For example in the `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` ?

Comment: @zlZimon Open [X509Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148581(v=vs.110).aspx). Store name should be [Root](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename(v=vs.110).aspx) for root ca certificates.

Comment: @pepo well thats what I thought. The X509Store.Name is "MY" and X509Store.Certificates.Count is 0. How is that possible? The import with mozroot finally worked and I can see the CAs in ~/Users/zlZimon/.config/.mono/certs

Comment: ok when I specify the store name I get 173 Root Ca for currentuser so that seems right, But how can I tell that this store is used when I build the chain?

Comment: @zlZimon hmm, look it up in mono sources :)

Comment: well I know that the current user store is used in the latest x509Chain implementation but does this also count for Mono 2.6.5?

Comment: @zlZimon You could check history of that file back to 2.6.x but IMHO I don't think that it was changed in any way.