# Validate a x509 certificate placed in a C folder

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, x509, x509certificate2

I have created a x509 certificate using open ssl, signed it with a key.
Now I want to validate/verify it in .Net for a desktop based application. I have placed it in a
C://certificate folder, want to read it from there.

I have followed the link [x509 validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613615/how-to-validate-x509-certificate), but did not find it of much use.

My goal is simple, to read it from c folder and validate it.

Is that Possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate X509 certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613615/how-to-validate-x509-certificate)

Comment: Could not figure that link on google search, will try. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the original question is sufficient and correct. [`X509Certificate2.Verify`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify) Method performs a X.509 chain validation using basic validation policy.

> This method builds a simple chain for the certificate and applies the base policy to that chain. If you need more information about a failure, validate the certificate directly using the X509Chain object.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
...
var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\certificate\yourcertfile.crt");

// Verify the certificate
bool isValid = cert.Verify();
```

But there are many factors that can affect the **validity** of an X.509 certificate, including the expiration date, the identity of the signer, and the chain of trust. So you may need to write your custom code for validation depending on **your specific requirements** if `Verify` is not enough for you.